# The Integral Trigonometric substitution better explanation

Tags: integration

The integral of
$$ \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} dx $$
with substitution $x=\sin(\theta)$ is
$$ \int \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{\cos^{2}(\theta)}} d \theta$$
If I notice, this can take two form, since it can be written as
$$ \int \frac{\cos(\theta)}{|\cos(\theta)|} d \theta$$
But why some textbooks (from what I have seen, for example : *Schaum's outline of Calculus*) does not account this? which means only take the positive value
$$ \int \frac{\cos(\theta)}{\sqrt{\cos^{2}(\theta)}} d \theta = \int  d \theta$$
Or, am i missing something here?

I presume that it is for simplicity in explanation. If so, which is the better one to be explained to freshmen students?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is very simple: a substitution must be defined with a *bijective* function. $\sin \theta$ is not bijective, so you have to restrict it to an interval on which it is bijective. The usual choice is the interval $\bigl[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\bigr]$ – and on this interval, it happens the cosine is non-negative.

Other than that, evey well-bred person should know the derivative of $\arcsin x\;$ is $\;\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, so the substitution is rather trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we must have $-1 < x < 1$. If we use $x = \sin \theta$, then we can assume that $-\dfrac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. It just so happens that $\cos \theta > 0$ in that region.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I hate it when I do that.

Comment: We all make typos (me first!)